# Atom Editor - how to show the current Ruby on Rails class methods in a right pane

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, navigation, atom-editor

I am using **Atom** as an IDE and I like it a lot.
The only problem I face is the inability to show the current class properties/methods in a right pane, just like, say, Zend Studio's Outline pane:

[image: Example]

[Another example - animated GIF (3.3MB)](https://i.github-camo.com/625e6d10dbc90e14696852bf0d4db63b4e1810b2/68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f786e64636e2f73796d626f6c732d747265652d766965772f6d61737465722f73637265656e636173742e6769663f7261773d74727565)

I have tried to use the **ruby-navigator** package, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the package https://atom.io/packages/symbols-tree-view
also, maybe you need generate ctags

ctags for rails projects generate examples:

`ctags -e --exclude=.git --exclude='*.log' -R *`bundle show --paths; pwd``

or

`` ctags -R --exclude=.git --exclude=log --exclude=tmp --exclude=autotest --exclude=db -f .tags * ~/.rvm/gems/`rvm current ``